# Geometry data для сервера MMORPG

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, буду вкратце. Есть MMORPG игра. Готовый клиент имеет достаточно большие локации, на котором много объектов. Движок игры использую Unity3D. Terrain также использую от движка. Для поиска пути монстра до персонажа, используется компонент NavMeshAgent. Сама AI монстров работает на сервере, где проверяется расстояния для агрессии. Если истина, то враг нападает. Проблема в том, что враг не знает о том, что существует какие-либо камни, заборы и т.д. Вопрос: как мне на сервере эмулировать локально карту? Для того чтобы мобы создали путь до игрока, который будет передаваться на клиент, и будет по нем идти?

Comment: "Создавать путь для игрока" - правильно я понял, что имеется в виду, что на сервере будет создаваться путь для монстра?

Comment: Монстр будет создавать путь, отталкиваясь от GeoData к персонажу. И двигаться в его сторону, в случаи если дистанция атаки выше нужной.

Comment: В TrinityCore (эмуляторе сервера World of Warcraft) используются экстракторы разных слоев карт для клиента, которые затем используются на сервере, чтобы тот имел информацию о всей геодате. Вероятно, вам нужно использовать тот же подход и скопировать если не все ресурсы из клиента на сервер, то как минимум участвующие в обработке игрового состояния.